# Checking derivative of norm squared of a linear transformation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

> Given $f: L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^k) \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f(A)=|Ax|^2$ and fix $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ then find $\partial_H f(A)$ where $H\in L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^k)$.

My attempt:
$$
\partial_H f(A) = \lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{|(A+t\cdot H)x|^2 - |Ax|^2)}{t}\right)\\
= \lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^k\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (a_{ji} + t\cdot h_{ji})x_i\right)^2-\sum_{j=1}^k\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ji}x_i\right)^2}{t}\right)\\
= \lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^k\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ji}x_i\right)^2 + 2t\sum_{j=1}^k\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (a_{ji}x_i) \sum_{i=1}^n(h_{ji}x_i)\right) + t^2\sum_{j=1}^k\left(\sum_{i=1}^n h_{ji} x_i\right)^2-\sum_{j=1}^k\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ji}x_i\right)^2}{t}\right)\\
= \left(2\sum_{j=1}^k\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (a_{ji}x_i) \sum_{i=1}^n(h_{ji}x_i)\right)\right)\\
$$
however I can't seem to simplify this further.

Answer (score 1):

Assume for the moment that the Frechet derivative $f'(A)$ exists. Then,

$\tag1f(A + v) = f(A) + f'(A)(v) + r(v)\  \text{where}\  \left|\frac{r(v)}{v}\right|\to 0\ \text{as}\ v\to 0.$

We have then

$\tag2\frac{f(A+tu)-f(A)}{t}=\frac{f'(A)(tu)+r(tu)}{t}\to f'(A)(u)\ \text{as}\ t\to 0.$

It follows that

$\tag3(Df_A)(u)=f'(A)(u)$

so it suffices to calculate $f'(A)(u).$

Now, $f$ is a compostion $A\overset  g\mapsto Ax\overset h\mapsto |Ax|^2$ and so $f'(A)$ does exist and is given by

$\tag4 f'(A)(u)=h'(g(A))(g'(A))(u)=h'(g(A))(g(u))$

because $g$ is linear. Then,

$\tag5 h'(g(A))(g(u))=h'(Ax)(ux)=2\langle Ax,ux\rangle.$

Comment: Could you please use the same notation as me, it becomes very hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Write the function in terms of the vector $y=Ax$ and calculate its differential.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= y^Ty \\
df &= 2y^Tdy = 2(Ax)^T(dA\,x) = 2x^TA^TdA\,x \\
}$$
Now substitute $\,dA=H\,dt\,$ to recover the desired derivative.
$$\eqalign{
\partial_Hf &= \left(\frac{df}{dt}\right) = 2x^TA^THx  \\
}$$

Comment: Where did $df = 2y^T dy$ come from? Also could you please use the same notation as me as saying $dy = d Ax$ is just wrong when you consider what the operator is.

Comment: @JohnMiller Poor notation is often an impediment to comprehension. Learn multiple notations, then choose the one that makes the most sense to you.

Comment: When you say $df$ what are you differentiating w.r.t? The $d$ means nothing.

Comment: Of course it means something. Take a look [at this paper](https://bridge.math.oregonstate.edu/papers/differentials.pdf) for example.

Comment: You're breaking $df/dy$ up even though the $df/dy$ is an operator not a fraction. That is a clear abuse of notation.

Comment: You also use the identity $\partial_H \left((Ax)^T (Ax)\right)= 2(Ax)^T$ with no proof.

Comment: @JohnMiller A clear abuse of notation?  Did you even _glance_ at the [linked paper](https://bridge.math.oregonstate.edu/papers/differentials.pdf)? You need to get familiar with more notations than what you've learned thus far.

Comment: I do not care for these arguments. But you still haven't told me where $\partial_H ((Ax)^T(Ax)) = 2(Ax)^T$ comes from which is the main part of the question.